# How to specify a model from these three plots?

Tags: arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

what kind of process is this? how can i see just from these graphs what kind of process this is? AR? MA? ARMA? ARIMA? [image: showing time-series and correlograms, how to tell what kind of process this is?]

Answer (score 1):

None of the peaks in the ACF or the PACF plot reach significance (apart, of course, from the very first peak in the ACF plot, which is always equal to $1$, because it is the autocorrelation of a time series with itself). This strongly suggests a simple white noise process, or ARIMA(0,0,0) if you want to be fancy.

[Consider using a modern automatic ARIMA model selection algorithm, rather than trying to read ACF/PACF plots.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6349/1352)